# Как удалить копию перенесённого объекта двойным кликом по нему и очистить dropzone

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop, удаление

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .drop {
        width: 150px;
        border-radius: 80px;
        background-color: blue;
      }
      div {
        height: 150px;
        background-color: #eee;
        width: 150px;
        border-radius: 80px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="drop" draggable="true"></div>

    <p>Dropzone</p>

    <div class="d2"></div>

    <script>
      var draggedEle = null;
      var divEle = document.querySelector(".drop");

      divEle.ondragstart = function (e) {
        draggedEle = e.target;
      };
      divEle.ondragend = function (e) {
        draggedEle = null;
      };

      var d2Ele = document.querySelector(".d2");
     

      d2Ele.ondragover = function (e) {
        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
        e.preventDefault();
        e.addEventListener("dbclick", function() {
          this.remove();
          })
      };

      d2Ele.ondrop = function (e) {
        if (draggedEle) {
          this.innerHTML = draggedEle.outerHTML;
        }
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как сделать, чтобы при двойном клике на перенесенную уже копию объекта класса "drop" в DropZone "d2". удалялся. То есть пользователь мог перенести, а затем при желание двойным кликом удалить копию drop